# what's the suggested build output folder layout for different OS/processor/debug/

Tags: makefile

ok i'm editing makefiles to build all these combinations:
ubuntu/suse
arm/i386/amd64
debug/release
bin/lib

how's the output folder layout should look like ?
do i care about ubuntu vs suse ?

Thanks !

Comment: Are you building from the same physical directory on multiple hosts? Then, yes, you do care. In normal case you are building only for single target, thus the differences (suse vs ubuntu, arm vs intel) are not relevant. But if you do, for the name of the directory you can use: (1) the "host/target triplet" as displayed by `gcc -dumpmachine` and (2) Ubuntu vs SUSE differences you have to handle manually, e.g. add the distro name to the host triplet.

Comment: @Dummy00001 yes i do need to care the difference, to simplify the case, the source is in the same build machine, i need to do cross-compiling. Ok i'll try the target/drstro/... triplet, thanks !

Comment: The GCC from my ARM toolchain says `arm-1136jfs-linux-gnueabihf`